# How can I implement MySql Transaction and FULL Text search if both are supported in different table types

Tags: mysql

I have all tables in `InnoDB` because I have implemented `MySql Transaction` (Commit / Rollback) in my scripts. Now I need to implement `FULL-TEXT` search functionality. When I tried to add FULL-TEXT index to the columns, I got an error that "`the used table type doesn't support full-text indexes`". How can I implement MySql Transaction and FULL-TEXT functionality on the same table?

Comment: Fulltext indexes for InnoDB require at least MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Okay, so if I upgrade the MySql to 5.6 then will it work?

Comment: Try before asking.